# How to i get a value out of a child of a table in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to i get a value out of a child of a table in Firebase ?

all the answers i keep finding on stack-overflow  have very little to no answers regarding this and i think it's really basic.

this is my table:
[image]

i want to fetch adam's pic or score data. without using the actual name "adam" but rather position number 0.

so far i can only get the size of the child, like this

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("table_one");
//
//                myRef.setValue("Check 2!");

                // Read from the database
                myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                        // whenever data at this location is updated.
//                        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("check", "count is: " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                        // Failed to read value
                        Log.w("check", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
                    }
                });
```

isn't there a simple way to get all the child for that table and look through them ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `ArrayList` and then use `list.get(0)`, like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference tableOneRef = rootRef.child("table_one");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String pic = ds.child("pic").getValue(String.class);
            list.add(pic);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", list.get(0));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
tableOneRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The restul in your output will be: `http://...`.

One more thing to mention is that `score` in your first object is of type `String` and in the second is of type `Integer`. Make sure to have the same type for `score` in all of your objects.

Answer (score 0):

get all children and make `Map` of userName and userImage

```
Map<String , String> usersWithImages = new HashMap<>();

...

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().rootRef.child("table_one").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String user = ds.getKey()
            String image = ds.child("pic").getValue(String.class);
            usersWithImages.put(user , image);
        }
    }
    ...
});

...

//some where
String adamImage = usersWithImages.get('adam');
System.out.println(adamImage);
```